# How to proceed with query automation using Import.io

Tags: import.io

I've successfully created a query with the Extractor tool found in Import.io. It does exactly what I want it to do, however I need to now run this once or twice a day. Is the purpose of Import.io as an API to allow me to build logic such as data storage and schedules tasks (running queries multiple times a day) with my own application or are there ways to scheduled queries and make use of long-term storage of my results completely within the Import.io service?

I'm happy to create a Laravel or Rails app to make requests to the API and store the information elsewhere but if I'm reinventing the wheel by doing so and they provides the means to address this then that is a true time saver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for using the new forum! Yes, we have moved this over to Stack Overflow to maximise the community atmosphere.

At the moment, Import does not have the ability to schedule crawls. However, this is something we are going to roll out in the near future.

For the moment, there is the ability to set a Cron job to run when you specify.

Comment: Thanks Meg! So there is a cron job option within import.io?

Comment: I investigated a bit and I think I see what you mean. It appears a lot of users setup cron jobs locally or on a server that will execute certain tasks periodically. Doesn't appear to be available within Import.io itself.

Comment: Hi, no, at the moment we do not offer that through Import. This is something that will be changing though. Yes, I usually set a cron job locally and run it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution if you are using the free version is to use a CI tool like travis or jenkins to schedule your API scripts.
You can query live the extractors so you don't need to make them run manually every time. This will consume one of your requests from your limit.

The endpoint you can use is:

```
https://extraction.import.io/query/extractor/extractor_id?_apikey=apikey&url=url
```

Unfortunately the script will not be a very simple one since most websites have very different respond structures towards import.io and as you may already know, the premium version of the tool provides now with scheduling capabilities.